# Showing $\log(2)$ and $\log(5)$

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion

How do I show that:

$$\log(2)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$$

and that

$$\log(5)=\log(3)+\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^n}{n3^n}$$

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you covered Abel's theorem?

Comment: $\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$

Comment: Yep, we did covered it

Comment: For the second, note that $\log(1+2/3)=\log(5/3)=\log5-\log3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n} \ \ \ ; \ \ \underbrace{ \forall\  0<x\le1}_{\text{important  condition}}$$
So,1st part:$$\log(1+1)$$
and for 2nd part: $$\log(1+2/3)=\log(5/3)=\log5-\log3$$

---

$$ln2=1-1/2+1/3-1/4+1/5-1/6+\dots$$
$$ln2=1/2+1/6+1/30+1/56+\dots\le 1+1/4+1/25+1/49+\dots$$
$$ln2\le 1+\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{k\in \  odd \ \Bbb  Z}\ \dfrac1{k^2}=1+\lim_{ n\to \infty}\sum_n \dfrac 1{(2n+1)^2}$$
$$\lim_{ n\to \infty}\sum_n \dfrac 1{(2n+1)^2} \text{ converges.}$$

So, $ln2$ will also converge.

Comment: Do you have a proof for the case $x=1$? (I know it is true, but since this sounds like homework, some justification is needed).

Comment: If you are allowing $x=1$ already, then you don't need a proof of convergence. (but to apply Abel's theorem, you do need it.)

Comment: The radius of convergence of the power series of $\log (1+x)$ is $1$. You need special justification to prove equality on the circle of convergence. $x=1$ is on that circle. If you are assuming that to be true, just setting $x=1$ will do. If you want to prove that is true, then what you have is incomplete: all you have shown is that $1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - \dots$ converges. Why should it equal $\log 2$?

Comment: @Aryabhata I'm just a high school student and don't know about this. `:p` sorry.

Comment: No worries :-) You can complete your proof using Abel's theorem. (If you are interested in knowing about that).

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

Expand using Taylor's theorem at $x = 1$.

See this link for more logarithmic [Taylor's applications](http://math2.org/math/expansion/log.htm).

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, use Abel's theorem to justify setting $x=1$ in

$$\log (1 + x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n}$$

The second comes from a plain substitution (as Daryl noted in the comments).