# Finding the Taylor series of $\log x$ at $x=1$ and $2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How do I find the Taylor series of the following functions:

$f(x)=\log(x)\ (x>0)$ at the point $x=1$

$g(x)=\log(x)\ (x>0)$ at the point $x=2$

Help greatly appreciated

Comment: You might try the formula from your book or on the web. How many terms do you need and what the kind of remainder do you want? Traditionally, if $f(x)$ has $n$ derivatives then $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f^{(k)}(c)(x-c)^k/k!+o((x-c)^n)$

Comment: The general formula for a Taylor series at point $a$ is $$f(a)+\frac {f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)+ \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+ \cdots$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing $\log(2)$ and $\log(5)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355597/showing-log2-and-log5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $\log(1)=0$ and $\log'(x)=x^{-1}$.

And the $n$-th derivative of $x^{-1}$
is 
$$D^n x^{-1} = (-1)^n \cdot n! \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}$$

And the taylor series is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(1)}{k!} \cdot (x-1)^k $$ 
and with our ideas above we get
$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \cdot x^k$$ 
Or 
$$\log(x)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k }{k} \cdot (x-1)^k $$

Comment: I think it should be $$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}, x\in(-1,1].$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x_0=1$ you have $f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)\cdot (x-1)+\frac{f^{''}(1)}{2}\cdot (x-1)^2+\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^n(1)}{n!}\cdot(x-1)^n$

Computing derivatives of $\log$ you finally get
$$\log x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x-1)^n}{n}$$
converging for $x\in(0,2]$

Similarly for $x_0=2$

Comment: The sries converge for $x\in (0,2]$ and @dato this site is about math and only about math

Comment: @DominicMichaelis you're absolutely right, i've edited